# Fetch newly listed created pairs on Raydium

Tags: python

I am facing following error:-
Error finding latest created pair: argument 'program': 'str' object cannot be converted to 'Pubkey'
when i try convert string to PublicKey.. It starts giving me import error of :- from solana.publickey import PublicKey

i have tried to import PublicKey with many alternative ways. However, none has seemed to work.
Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

#Here is the Code:-

from solana.rpc.api import Client

rpc_url = 'https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/'
solana_client = Client(rpc_url)

RAYDIUM_PROGRAM_ID = "675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8"

def find_latest_created_pair():
try:
raydium_accounts = solana_client.get_program_accounts(RAYDIUM_PROGRAM_ID)

```
    latest_created_pair = max(
        raydium_accounts,
        key=lambda account: account.get('data', {}).get('created_at', 0)
    )

    print('Latest Created Pair:', latest_created_pair)
except Exception as e:
    print('Error finding latest created pair:', e)
```

find_latest_created_pair()

Comment: What does this code return? the pair address or what?

Comment: How do you get the pubkey? I am trying the same code above and i continue to get an error with no exception print out.

Answer (score 1):

If `Pubkey` is not available directly from the solana package, you may be using a newer version of `solana-py`, which requires types from the `solders` package. See the note at the [README](https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/tree/master#solanapy):

> Note: This library uses many core types from the Solders package which used to be provided by solana-py itself. If you are upgrading from an old version and you're looking for something that was deleted, it's probably in solders now.

So to fix this, you just need to add `solders` to your project, then add:

```
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
```

Then you'll be able to convert your string to a Pubkey with:

```
RAYDIUM_PROGRAM_ID = Pubkey.from_string("675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to this

```
import asyncio
import sys

import websockets
import json
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
from solders.signature import Signature
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate


wallet_address = "675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8"
seen_signatures = set()
solana_client = Client("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com")

def  getTokens(str_signature):
    signature = Signature.from_string(str_signature)
    transaction = solana_client.get_transaction(signature, encoding="jsonParsed",max_supported_transaction_version=0).value
    instruction_list = transaction.transaction.transaction.message.instructions
    if any("initialize2" in message for message in transaction.transaction.meta.log_messages):
        for instructions in instruction_list:
            if instructions.program_id == Pubkey.from_string(wallet_address):
                print("============NEW POOL DETECTED====================")
                Token0= instructions.accounts[8]
                Token1= instructions.accounts[9]
                # Your data
                data = {'Token_Index': ['Token0', 'Token1'],
                        'Account Public Key': [Token0, Token1]}

                df = pd.DataFrame(data)
                table = tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='fancy_grid')
                print(table)
             


async def run():
   uri = "wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
   async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
       # Send subscription request
       await websocket.send(json.dumps({
           "jsonrpc": "2.0",
           "id": 1,
           "method": "logsSubscribe",
           "params": [
               {"mentions": [wallet_address]},
               {"commitment": "finalized"}
           ]
       }))

       first_resp = await websocket.recv()
       response_dict = json.loads(first_resp)
       if 'result' in response_dict:
          print("Subscription successful. Subscription ID: ", response_dict['result'])

       # Continuously read from the WebSocket
       async for response in websocket:
          
           response_dict = json.loads(response)

           if response_dict['params']['result']['value']['err'] == None :
               signature = response_dict['params']['result']['value']['signature']

               if signature not in seen_signatures:
                  seen_signatures.add(signature)
                  log_messages_set = set(response_dict['params']['result']['value']['logs'])

                  search="initialize2"
                  if any(search in message for message in log_messages_set):
                      print("True",signature)
                      getTokens(signature)

                 
           else:
               pass


async def main():
    await run()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Github repo can be found [here](https://github.com/henrytirla/Decentralized-Exchange-Trading-Scripts)